# Resharper NUnit geen/yellow code bullets gone in my VS, in the middle of a VS run session

Tags: nunit, resharper

Morning it was there when I started my VS 2015. I've run some unit tests. Then without exiting VS, it was gone. I mean: Resharper does not discover NUnit unit tests anymore: No yellow/green helpers left side. I *can* run tests from Solution Explorer's context menu.

The strangest thing is I did not install changed anything at least I do not know about it.

What I've tried:

- Exit VS / Start VS
- Restart my PC
- Open an other project (detto: no green/yellow helpers in code editor)
- Check Resharpers related options: NUnit is checked, MSTest unchecked

Versions:

- Nunit: 2.6.4.14350 (via nuget)
- Resharper: 10.0.2
- VS: 14.0.23107

Comment: Try clearing the Resharper Cache and remove the .suo file as it may have become corrupt.

Comment: Thanks, that is an answer, please post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clearing the Resharper Cache (`Resharper`->`Options...`->`General`->`Clear Caches`) and remove the .suo file as it may have become corrupt.